# For Loop vs While Loop

Tags: loops, language-agnostic, compiler-construction, for-loop, while-loop

In my lecture of Design and Analysis of
Algorithms the instructor said the for loop will take less time then while loop for the following sample algo.

```
1.  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {    
2.      print(i);    
    }

1.  int i=0;
2.  while(i<5)
    {    
3.      print(i);    
4.      i++;    
    }
```

He said that the compiler will read the 1. of for while 5 times line 2. 4 times thus total time 5+4=9
But in the case of while loop. The compiler will read the  1. for 1 time,2. for 5 time, 3 for 4time and 4. for 4 time. Thus total time 1+5+4+4 = 14time
Please tell me is this right. Is for loop is faster than while loop?

Thanks.

Comment: A compiler set to opmizing for speed might just emit `print(i)` five times and eliminate the loop altogether. In both cases.

Comment: In the real world we look at legibility of the code and pick either `for` or `while` depending on that. The compiler will either optimize the difference out. Or the difference is so small on modern machines that it is negligible. Use the one that makes your life easier, not the "life" of the computer.

Comment: and if not set to optimizing then??

Comment: i'm pretty sure the compiler will read each line just once ;)

Comment: As this is very language/compiler specific you should add the information to your question/tags!

Comment: The compiler will definetly read each line only once. Since it's basically the same set of instuctions ether way, it should make no difference at runtime. Strange instuctor though.

Comment: @soulcheck then which gonna be faster???

Comment: @wali the problem is in your problem description. it's not about what will compiler read and how many times, it's the code it will generate. In this case it will probably be the same set of instructions with any modern compiler, with the exception that in second case you're not declaring the variable.

Comment: @soulcheck i forgot to declare. these are separate pieces of code. U said it will probably the same. i want to know what actually gonna happen...

Comment: wali, what stops you from simply *trying it out?*

Answer (score 6):

At least with MSVC 16 (VS 2010) the code is pretty much the same in both cases:

**for**

```
; Line 5
    xor esi, esi
$LL3@main:
; Line 6
    push    esi
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_03PMGGPEJJ@?$CFd?6?$AA@
    call    _printf
    inc esi
    add esp, 8
    cmp esi, 5
    jl  SHORT $LL3@main
```

**while**

```
; Line 4
    xor esi, esi
$LL2@main:
; Line 6
    push    esi
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_03PMGGPEJJ@?$CFd?6?$AA@
    call    _printf
; Line 7
    inc esi
    add esp, 8
    cmp esi, 5
    jl  SHORT $LL2@main
```

Code [in my Subversion repository](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/9326919).

Comment: Thanks for *sanity*. (note that only the debug information and label names are different)

Answer (score 2):

In all the modern compilers [loop analysis](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs553/Slides/lecture12-control.ppt.pdf) is done on a lower level intermediate representation (i.e., when all the high level loop constructs are expanded into labels and jumps). For a compiler both loops are absolutely equivalent.

Comment: what logical reason or proof i can provide to argue with him.

Comment: @wali, show him the assembly output for both versions, give this slides, show a relevant transform implementation in either `gcc` or `llvm` (which are quite typical representatives of the modern compilers).

Answer (score 2):

I'll pass on performance (hint: no difference, check the generated IR or assembly for proof) however there are two important differences in *syntax* and *maintenance*.

**Syntax**

The scope of the `i` variable is different. In the `for` case, the `i` is only accessible within the `for` *header* and *body*, while in the `while` case it is available after the loop. As a general rule, it's better to have tighter scopes, less variables *in-flight* mean less context to worry about when coding.

**Maintenance**

The `for` loop has the neat advantage of grouping all the iterations operations close together, so they can be inspected in one shot and so checked.

Also, there is one important difference when introducing `continue` statements:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
  if (array[i] == nullptr) { continue; }
  // act on it
}


int i = 0;
while (i != 10) {
  if (array[i] == nullptr) { continue; }
  // act on it
  ++i;
}
```

In the `while` case, the introduction of `continue` has created a bug: an infinite loop, as the counter is no longer implemented.

**Impact**

`for` loops are more readable and all-around better for *regular* iteration patterns. Even better, in C++11 the range-for statement:

```
for (Item const& item : collection) {
}
```

where iteration is entirely taken care of by the compiler, so you are sure not to mess up! (it makes the `for_each` algorithm somewhat moot... and we can wish the older for form starts retreating)

By corrolary: `while` loops should be reserved to irregular iteration patterns, this way they will attract special care during code review and from future maintainer by *highlighting* the *irregularity* of the case.